# Visual Studio Express 2013 freezes when opening project properties

Tags: c++, dll, linker, visual-studio-2013

## Main Problem

When I try to access the properties of a project in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop through `Project -> ProjectName Properties`, Visual Studio freezes completely without an error and I must end it through the Windows Task Manager.

I ran Visual Studio with /safemode enabled. This did provide some information by saying that `"The 'Visual Studio Component Model Host Package' package did not load correctly."`

It also produced a log file with some errors and warnings. Errors and warning entries in the log can be searched for with `<type>Error</type>` and `<type>Warning</type>` respectively. Additionally, opening the file in Internet Explorer seems to apply some styles to the file and makes it more readable.

Errors only - http://pastebin.com/295sX8kH

Full log - http://pastebin.com/KGspUgGs

The errors in the log seem to center around this `Visual Studio Component Model Host Package`. I tried searching for errors related to that, but did not find anything I thought was applicable to my situation.

The dll `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.Implementation.dll` is present in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\`

The dll `Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DataSourceWizardExtension.dll` is indeed missing from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\DataDesign`

## Extra Info

I am using version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3 of Visual Studio and I am running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit 6.1 build 7601.

I have tried re-installing Visual Studio in order to to clear out any bad settings, but that did not seem to work.

I tried running Visual Studio with /resetskipkgs and /resetsettings, and neither of those worked.

Trying to open project properties in safe mode still froze Visual Studio.

## Backstory

I am ultimately trying to setup an environment in which to develop OpenGL applications. I have some experience with it through following the Arc Synthesis tutorials, but I do not know how to operate outside of the specialized environment the tutorials provided.

Following the OpenGL Book setup instructions, I am told development will go more smoothly if I use the GLEW and freeGLUT libraries. In order to do so, I need to be able to link in extra files to a project. In Visual Studio, this is done through the project properties dialog, but I cannot access it due to the freezing problem.

I am not very familiar with the development process in C++, so I am wary of venturing outside of the IDE provided by Visual Studio, but I might just have to do that if this problem persists.